# Running simple_smartsheet on Python 3.7, unable to find 'pd' definition in read Excel call

Tags: python, excel, smartsheet-api

I've looked through StackOverflow and found a related question about a script that reads an excel file, read the row from excel, then write the row to Smartsheet.

I am getting an error where the 'pd' is not defined when I run the script to read an Excel file.

**Does anyone know where the 'pd' id defined?  I couldn't find it. Is there another way to do this?**

**RUN**

> pi@cenicapi:~/Documents/tscripts $ ./sample.s
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "./sample.s", line 16, in 
> data = pd.read_csv(r'Sample.xlsx')
> NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
> pi@cenicapi:~/Documents/tscripts $

**SCRIPT CODE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7

import logging
import csv
import os

# Log all calls
logging.basicConfig(filename='rwsheet.log', level=logging.INFO)

from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType

data = **pd**.read_csv(r'Sample.xlsx')
df = **pd**.DataFrame(data, columns=[ 'ccc_key_id', 'MyDate', 'CCD', 'Max In Only', 'Max Out Only', 'avg_bits_out_min'])

example = df.values.tolist()
print(example)
```

**Appreciate any help**

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, pd is referring to the pandas module (https://pandas.pydata.org/). A lot of people abbreviate `pandas` as `pd`, and I myself use that very same one!

Problem should be solved with a simple

```py
import pandas as pd
```

at the very beginning, right after import os should work. Although you will want to make sure pandas is installed in your environment!